# Call User Control Method in Master Page from Content Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, master-pages

I have a Custom User Control present in my master page that loads site-wide JavaScript libraries into the master page's head

Like so:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <CustomControl:MyScriptControl id="scripts" runat="server" />
    </head>

    <body>

        <asp:ContententPlaceHolder id="pageContent" runat="server" />

    </body>

</html>
```

I would like to have the page that uses the MasterPage call a method of the User Control **MyScriptControl** so essentially

```
public partial class ChildPage: System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

          //// Invoke Method of MasterPage's UserControl: MyScriptControl

    }
}
```

Is this possible ? Or is there a better way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Add a MasterType directive in your aspx page
 Step 2: Create a public method in your master page which will call your usercontrol method.
 Step 3: From your page you can call that method using Master.Method()

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [MasterType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228274%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) directive in your page.

Using MasterType, your page's `Master` property will be of the type of your master page, and not of the base class `MasterPage`. You should be able to do something like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Master.scripts.SomeMethod();
}
```