# Call user control's function from page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have one user control with few events/functions registered on Master Page. My current aspx page is inherited from this master page file. I want to call user control's function on button click event of aspx page. Please help.

Comment: I've checked that question. In my case, user control is registered with Master page

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019598/call-user-control-method-in-master-page-from-content-page